# Finding a relation between two sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am using the textbook Elementary Analysis. I am having trouble solving the following problem:
Let $A$ be a set of real numbers and let $B=\{-x \mid x \in A\}$. Find a relation between $\max(A)$ and $\min(B)$ and between $\max(B)$ and $\min(A)$.
I know that the min of $A$ is the max of $B$ and that the max of $A$ is the min of $B$. I am not sure what it means when it says "find a relation". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Equality is a relation.

Comment: $\max, \min$? or $\sup$, $\inf$. What if $A$ is not bounded above or below. "relationship" would probably be a better word. In any case, as @ClementC. notes, equality is a relationship.

Comment: It does not specify, it just states find a relation between min and max.

Comment: Hi Clement, so equality is the relation being described? I only need to state that $max(A)=min(B)$ and vice versa?

Comment: Are you sure there's only one textbook author in history who has come up with the brilliantly creative and specific title "Elementary Analysis"? If you are, then you're somewhat justified in not revealing who wrote your particular "Elementary Analysis".

Comment: Thomson/Bruckner

Comment: NO, they might not exist. $\max A$ exists *iff* $\min -A $ exists, and then ... some relationship holds between them. It's **not** $\max A = \min - A$, *that's false*, so you can't "know" it. You need one more symbol... . Examples: $A=\{1,2\}, A=\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$.

Comment: @JanetSharma you are missing a minus sign there, but yes (if they exist, as BrianO points out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

A little bit of graph is always a good thing to do. As you can see in the graphic example, the desired relationship is that $\max A=-\min B$ (we assume that set $A$ has a maximum, although it should have been stated by the assumptions). Indeed, if $a\in A$ is such that $x\leq a$ for 
all $a\in A$ (i.e. $a=\max A$), then $-x\geq -a$ for all $x\in A$, equivalently $y\geq -a$ for all $y\in B$, meaning that $\min B=-a=-\max A,$ as desired.